# Dockerfile create mariadb image

Tags: docker

hello everyone i want to create a docker image from centos 7 with mariadb installed and running. the image created but mariadb won’t start. can anyone please help me.

This Is My Dockerfile.

#

FROM centos:7

MAINTAINER HAMZA_BENHAMANI

RUN yum install mariadb-server -y \

EXPOSE 3306

CMD [“mysqld”]

#

Thanks.

Comment: Without more information we can only guess what's wrong. For example, what is in the log when you start the container?

Comment: it doesn't start

Comment: i need the proper CMD OR ENTRYPOINT To start mariadb